# The type or namespace name 'Timers' does not exist in the namespace 'system'

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps

I am getting this error when I am adding 'using System.Timers' in visual studio 2013

```
using System.Timers;
```

Error:

> The type or namespace name 'Timers' does not exit in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: What kind of project?

Comment: I am making a game and from here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18338251/how-do-i-make-a-loop-for-a-game-that-runs-every-number-of-milliseconds ) I came to know how to use timer in c# but it is showing above error.

Comment: It is a PCL for example? Silverlight?

Comment: `System.Timers` is the wrong kind of timer; you want to stay on the UI thread.  What kind of project?

Comment: It is visual c#->store apps->windows apps->blank app

Comment: Then indeed you experience the issue I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not very sharing I created a test project. A [PCL (Portable Class Library)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/gg597391%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) project. I just took all platforms, including Silverlight 5.

When I add the `using` you are talking about, it indeed says the namespace doesn't exist. So it seems to be you have a project type that doesn't support `System.Timers`.

To support [Guffa's assumption](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27767891/993547) of removing the `System` assembly, indeed, that gives the exact same error message too.

Answer (score 2):

The `System.Timers` namespace is in the `System.dll` assembly.

Either you have accidentally removed the reference to `System.dll`, or you have created some other identifier named `System` that is interfering with your declaration.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Timers; I have also used other namespaces and are working, the problem is only with Timers

Comment: @RobbinSingh: Then the only remaining explanation is that you are using a platform that isn't supposed to have system timers in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your project you might need to add a reference to be able to import the namespace.

To do open your project explorer and rightclick "references" -> "add reference"